# Codeigniter - Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated CI version 3.1.6

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

controller

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Mbussinesstype extends MY_Model{
        private $data = null;
        public  $table_name = null;
        public  $primary_key = null;
        public  $sql = null;

        function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->table_name   = 'bussinesstype';
          $this->primary_key  = 'id';
          $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE 1=1  ";             
        }

        function SetDetails() {
            $this->data   = array(
                   'name_en'              => ucfirst(trim($this->input->post('name_en'))),
                   'name_np'              => trim($this->input->post('name_np')),         
                   'status'               => $this->input->post('status')                      
                );
        }
```

I am newer in codeignater , this error happened to me when i change php version , previous version is lower then 7 and when now php version is 7.1.4 , before version chenge the code is running smothly bt now this error is shown below ..

Severity: 8192

Message: Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated

Filename: libraries/Encryption.php

Line Number: 35

Backtrace:

File: E:\xampp\htdocs\dryice\application\libraries\Encryption.php
Line: 35
Function: _error_handler

File: E:\xampp\htdocs\dryice\application\modules\bussinesstype\controllers\Admin.php
Line: 35
Function: decode

File: E:\xampp\htdocs\dryice\application\modules\bussinesstype\controllers\Admin.php
Line: 11
Function: record

File: E:\xampp\htdocs\dryice\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Answer (score 0):

According the PHP Documentation :

> mcrypt_get_iv_size is deprecated as of PHP 7.1.0

[Link to PHP mcrypt_get_iv_size](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-iv-size.php)

You should use `mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size` in PHP later than 7.1.0

[Link to PHP mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-enc-get-iv-size.php)

Comment: Also deprecated